# How to do HTTP GET request with an object and not by id or another variable?

Tags: kotlin, retrofit

I have to fetch from here

> api/v1/departments/{department}

but the department object has only a name and location variable.

```
  data class Department (
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("name")
    val name : String?,
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("location")
    val location: String?
) : Serializable
```

Here is my function for this request:

```
 @GET("departments/{department}")
 fun getDepartment(@Path("department")  name: Department?) : Call<Department>
```

So far I have fetched only by id. How do I do a HTTP GET request by an object?

Comment: Problem is not very clear. But why can't  your "name" in fun getDepartment be just a String? Did you try to fetch result from this endpoint with the Postman for example?

Comment: I tried with name to be String, it works neither in the app nor in Postman.

Comment: Well, first you should get success with postman